# Request in C# Not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting

hello I am looking to use a header to push values from my unity project into a ASPX string. I was wondering how to do this. I can do it in PHP with a simple $_Request(ID) then using that like

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewSession : MonoBehaviour {

                string userLoginFile = "http://local/UnitySQL/NewSession.php?UserId=";
                public UnityEngine.UI.Text NewSess;                     

                string userid = "";
                string session = "";

               void OnGUI()
                {
                                session = NewSess.text;
                                userid = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("UserId");
                }



                public void Insert()
                {
                                if (session == "") {
                                                Application.OpenURL (userLoginFile +userid);
                                                //StartCoroutine (LoginUser (userid));
                                } else {
                                                print("DAMNSON");
                                }
                }




                /*IEnumerator LoginUser(string user)
                {

                                WWW login = new WWW (userLoginFile + "UserId=" + user);
                                print (userLoginFile + "UserId=" + user);
                                yield return login;

                                if (login.error == null)
                                {

                                                string[] credentials = login.text.Split('/');

                                                foreach(string str in credentials)
                                                {
                                                                string[] creds = str.Split ('=');

                                                                for(int i=0; i < creds.Length; i++)
                                                                {
                                                                                print ("winner");
                                                                }


                                                }
                                }

                }*/
}

Then the PHP would just be a simple 
                $userid = $_REQUEST['UserId'];
```

UID = $_REQUEST(ID);

I was wondering how i would do this using C# 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by ASPX string?  Your question is very unclear as currently written.

Comment: Please post your code that was written till now. Then, it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to get a handle on the HTTP Request. Take a look at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Example for documentation:

```
    public partial class AddToCart : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rawId = Request["ProductID"];
        int productId;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawId) && int.TryParse(rawId, out productId))
        {
            using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartActions())
            {
                usersShoppingCart.AddToCart(productId);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Tried to call AddToCart.aspx without setting a ProductId.");
        }
        Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
    }
}
```